# How do I set rack and datacenter name for scylladb using docker?

Tags: docker, cassandra, scylla

Scylladb builds on many of the same paradigms as Cassandra. When starting a Cassandra instance via docker, its rack and datacenter name can be specified directly from the command line like this:

```
docker run --name c1 -d tobert/cassandra -rack myRack -dc myDatacenter
```

However, I have failed to obtain the same behavior with Scylladb. Is it possible to specify the rack and datacenter names from the docker command line? If not: how can these (and other) configuration parameters then be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ScyllaDB Docker image does not currently support the options but you can manually change the /etc/scylla/cassandra-rackdc.properties file to configure them.

I opened an issue about the missing configuration options: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/2048